# C# ASP.NET Metodo Get com parametro retornando 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

Boa tarde pessoal,eu gostaria de saber se alguém pode me auxiliar. Meu Web Service tem um método Get que retorna toda a lista de Produtos, entretanto eu gostaria de criar um método que ele retornasse UM Produto segundo um código que passassem para ele. No momento tudo o que o método com parametro está me retornando é um 404 quando testado no Fiddler. Alguma ideia? Algum metodo que vcs tenham? qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda obrigado.

***Código:***

```
[Route("api/Produto")]
public class ProdutoConsultController : ApiController
{


    // GET api/ProdutoConsult
    public ObjectResult<uspConsultarProduto_Result> Get()
    {
        ControleDeEstoqueEntities entity = new ControleDeEstoqueEntities();
        var result = entity.uspConsultarProduto(null);
        return result;
    }

    // GET api/ProdutoConsult/5
    public List<produto> Get(int cod)
    {
        ControleDeEstoqueEntities entity = new ControleDeEstoqueEntities();
        List<produto> MyList = new List<produto>();
        var result = from produto in entity.produto where produto.pro_cod == cod select produto;
        MyList.AddRange(result);

        return MyList;
    }
```

Comment: Mantenha a pergunta no estado inicial, senão ela perde o sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `Route` não está sendo usado corretamente.

Você deve usá-los nas actions e não no *controller*, no *controller* deve-se usar `RoutePrefix` para definir um "prefixo" para a rota.

```
public class ProdutoConsultController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Produto")]
    public ObjectResult<uspConsultarProduto_Result> Get()
    {
        // Retornar todos
    }

    [Route("api/Produto/{cod}")]
    public List<produto> Get(int cod)
    {
        // retornar um
    }
}
```

Comment: MUITO obrigado pelo esclarecimento jbueno,vc é meu salvador KKKK isso explica pq n tava dando certo.